# Maps between finite sets

Tags: list-manipulation, map, sets

With [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), one can do `FiniteSetMaps(["a", "b"], [3, 4, 5])` to get all maps from `{a,b}` to `{3,4,5}`. Is something similar available in Mathematica?

Comment: In terms of `Function` or ordered pairs or `Rule`?

Comment: In general you should show what the expected output should look like. Note also that on a Mathematica forum you should not expect readers to know Sage or require them to search for Sage commands.

Comment: SAGE reference page for [Maps between finite sets](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/sets/sage/sets/finite_set_maps.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
alist = {3, 4, 5};
blist = {"a", "b"};
mapfs = Tuples@Outer[Rule, blist, alist]
```

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \{\text{a}\to 3,\text{b}\to 3\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 3,\text{b}\to 4\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 3,\text{b}\to 5\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 4,\text{b}\to 3\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 4,\text{b}\to 4\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 4,\text{b}\to 5\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 5,\text{b}\to 3\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 5,\text{b}\to 4\} \\
 \{\text{a}\to 5,\text{b}\to 5\} \\
\end{array}$$

---

**EDIT**

Following comment by @Alan (Thanks)

```
mapasc = Map[Association, mapfs]
mapasc[[2]]["b"]
```

> 4

Comment: How can the elements in `mapfs` be made executable, for example `mapfs[[2]]["b"] ` should return `4`?

Comment: `Last@Values@mapfs[[2]]`

Comment: For that, I have to know in which position `b` is. How can a function in mapfs be made executable by its respective argument like "a" or "b"?

Comment: `"b" /. mapfs[[2]]`

Comment: @Thrash Just map `Association` over `mapfs`.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in function but the following constructs the mappings:

```
aa = {"a", "b"};
bb = {3, 4, 5};
Thread[aa -> #] & /@ Tuples[bb, Length@aa]
```

If you want "functional" expressions, then one way to get them is

```
funcs = ReplaceAll@Thread[aa -> #] & /@ Tuples[bb, Length@aa]

funcs[[2]]["b"]
(*  4  *)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it first in a more direct way via `f/@aa = {3,4}` for example, but I get `Set::write: Tag Map in f /@ {a, b} is Protected.`. Why can't be several values assigned at once?

Comment: @Thrash Try `Evaluate[f /@ aa] = {3, 4}`.